# touchesBegan error ; everywhere I touch on the screen the game crashes

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, touchesbegan

So, I'm making a game for the iOS and it's literally all done except now my touchesBegan function is causing errors. This is how my function is laid out right now:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var doo = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if GameOver{
            var gameScene = EasyScene(size: self.size)
            gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
            self.scene!.view?.presentScene(gameScene)
        }
        else{
            if red.containsPoint(location){ // This is Line A
                //takeOut(red)
                red.removeFromParent()
                score++
                scoreNode.text = String(score)
                print("-hi")
            }
            if red1.containsPoint(location){
                red1.removeFromParent()
                score++
                scoreNode.text = String(score)
                //takeOut(red1)
                print("-hel")
            }
            if red2.containsPoint(location){
                red2.removeFromParent()
                score++
                scoreNode.text = String(score)
                //takeOut(red2)
                print("-hell")
            }
            if red3.containsPoint(location){
                red3.removeFromParent()
                score++
                scoreNode.text = String(score)
                //takeOut(red3)
                print("-hello")
            }
            if red4.containsPoint(location){
                red4.removeFromParent()
                //takeOut(red4)
                score++
                scoreNode.text = String(score)
                print("-hellow")
            }
            if red5.containsPoint(location){
                red5.removeFromParent()
                score++
                scoreNode.text = String(score)
                // takeOut(red5)
                print("-hellowor")
            }
            if blue.containsPoint(location){
                GameOver = true
            }
            if blue1.containsPoint(location){
                GameOver = true
            }
            if blue2.containsPoint(location){
                GameOver = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the issue is that when **GameOver is false**: anything I touch on-screen will cause a crash. If I touch the screen (no spriteNode in particular) it points to the line labeled "This is Line A" however if I tap on a node that is actually on the screen, the game will crash and point towards the spriteNode that I pressed saying the same thing:

```
fatal error: unexpected nil while unwrapping optional value
```

also when **GameOver == true** toouchesBegan works fine

Comment: Before your question can be answered, you must give us your `!` key.

Comment: @nhgrif what is that? I am not familiar with that

Comment: So the 'unexpected nil...' Error occurs at line A? It looks like red is nil - have you checked in the debugger whether this is the case?

Comment: @AliBeadle  I think that may be the issue, however I've already declared what red is. Its in another function but in the same class

Comment: @CoolMAn Is that other function called before this one? Is it correctly initialising red? Is red becoming nil later for some reason? It looks like the problem is outside the code you have posted. Try tracking down whether red really is nil and why using the debugger.

Comment: @AliBeadle the function is indeed called before touchesBegan. Also how could red become nil afterwards, I'm pretty sure it isn't though.

Comment: @CoolMAn it could be assigned to nil or perhaps it only has weak references and is being deallocated - this is what 'unexpected nil found...' means so something there is nil. 1: is red nil? Check using the debugger if this is your problem. 2: if it is nil find out where this is happening and why. 3: if red is not nil find out what is.

Comment: @AliBeadle you were right to give me such advice! I assigned my red sprite in a function that wasn't being called until 5 seconds had passed after the apps execution. I found that my app didn't crash if I declare what my red sprite is in the didMoveToView function. Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

The reason my game was crashing was because I had declared what my sprite was in a function that I had programmed to be executed 5 seconds after initial start of my app. However I find that the game runs properly now that my red sprite is declared in didMoveToView